# need Database writing to happen in NSNotification call-back method

Tags: iphone, nsnotification

I make a call to a web service, passing a parameter and then register an observer in a viewcontroller class (to notify completion of download) :

```
[self callWebservice:parameter1];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(dataDownloadComplete:) name:OP_DataComplete object:nil];
```

and then post a notification in my parser class:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection method of the parser  class. [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:OP_DataComplete object:nil];
```

In the callback method dataDownloadComplete: i would like to call the same web service again several times.

```
-(void)dataDownloadComplete
{
 if([anArray objectAtindex:N]<10)
  {
   [self callWebservice:parameterN];
   NSLog(@"This is getting called everytime (9 times)");
   [self writeintoDatabase];
   N++;
  }
}
```

But the problem is that i want to write into a database what data i download from the service. The DB writing happens for 'parameter1' call strangely, and goes on for the others but not for parameter9(which i need as well). Note the Log is called all 9 times though. The writeintoDatabase code is perfect. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're saying this works 8 times and then fails on the 9th one? Is dataDownloadComplete being called the correct number of times? I would put a log in there to be sure. Also, I'm guessing parameterN and N are related somehow in your real code?

Comment: yes it's called 8 times . Also note that i don't call it the first time (for the call that is outside the observer code), yet that is getting written. Let me edit the code , i have used logs. The Log gets printed 9 times strangely. ParameterN is a string and N is an integer both variables.

Comment: ParameterN is a string? Then how are you comparing it to 10? In any case, it sounds like you're getting 9 notifications, which you expect. So that tells me the problem is in -[xx writeintoDatabase:], don't you think?

Comment: this is not the actual code , by parameterN i actually mean [anArray objcetAtindex:N]